# Unable to read and write list of double in parcelable

Tags: android, list, double, parcelable

I have a class having list of doubles. My class is implementing parcelable. I am getting no clue how to read and write double as parcelable.

Following is my class

```
public class CinemasModel implements Parcelable{

@SerializedName("ll")
private ArrayList<Double> mLl;

@SerializedName("films")
private List<FilmsModel> mFilms;

protected CinemasModel(Parcel in) {
    mLl = new ArrayList<>();
    in.readValue(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    mFilms = new ArrayList<FilmsModel>();
    in.readList(this.mFilms, null);
}

public static final Creator<CinemasModel> CREATOR = new Creator<CinemasModel>() {
    @Override
    public CinemasModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CinemasModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CinemasModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CinemasModel[size];
    }
};

public CinemasModel(ArrayList<Double> ll, List<FilmsModel> films){
    this.mLl = ll;
    this.mFilms = films;
}

public CinemasModel(){

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeValue(mLl);
    parcel.writeList(mFilms);
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the class `FilmModels` implement `Parceable` aswell ?

Comment: In `writeToParcel` why dont you `parcel.writeList(mLl)` ?

Comment: Doesn't work @Greggz and FilmModel do implement Parcelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you write code for parcelable? [here is parcelebale plugin to
  autogenerate it](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator).
- Remember you will need to make FilmsModel class also parcelable.

Below code works well, generated by above parcelable plugin.

```
public class CinemasModel implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("ll")
    private ArrayList<Double> mLl;

    @SerializedName("films")
    private List<FilmsModel> mFilms;

    protected CinemasModel(Parcel in) {
        this.mLl = new ArrayList<Double>();
        in.readList(this.mLl, Double.class.getClassLoader());
        this.mFilms = new ArrayList<FilmsModel>();
        in.readList(this.mFilms, FilmsModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CinemasModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CinemasModel>() {
        @Override
        public CinemasModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CinemasModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public CinemasModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CinemasModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for plugin update (Y) @Khemraj